# Closing a Windows handle to a remote file with severed connection

Tags: c++, windows, function, remote-access

Refering here:

> Generally, an application should call CloseHandle once for each handle it opens. It is usually not necessary to call CloseHandle if a function that uses a handle fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, because this error usually indicates that the handle is already invalidated. However, some functions use ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE to indicate that the object itself is no longer valid. For example, a function that attempts to use a handle to a file on a network might fail with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE if the network connection is severed, because the file object is no longer available. In this case, the application should close the handle. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle

I just don't understand. So if connection is severed and I try to close a handle will it fail because handle is invalid? But what will happen if connection is restored? Main application process will restore it's ownership over a file? If I am right, it's a big leak. And how to handle this scenario? Is there any standart way?

Answer (score 2):

The following explanation may answer your questions.

From Raymond Chen's [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130916-00/?p=3233),

> **Forcing a network file handle closed does not actually close the
> handle.** This makes it very different from the various “force handle
> closed” utilities out there. Rather, forcing a network file handle
> closed is accomplished by simulating a network failure, **so that when
> the remote machine tries to use the handle again, it’s told, “Wha? I’m
> sorry, we must have a bad connection, because I’m not sure what you’re
> talking about.”** Since programs which access network resources must
> deal with the possibility of network connectivity loss, this deception
> does not violate the interface contract.
>
> (**Doing this to handles to local resources is a much riskier
> undertaking, because applications expect access to local files to
> remain valid for the lifetime of the handle.** There is no equivalent of
> transient network connectivity failure for local files on
> non-removable drives. There is also no API for simulating it.)

Hope to help you.